# Postgres / preserve json column data across updates

Tags: json, postgresql, merge

Having a table with a jsonb column, am looking for a way to elegantly handling json columns updates without loosing previously inserted data. I'd need to set this within postgres capabilities (a function, a trigger, etc...)

For example, for a given record already existing with the following :

```
| jsoncolumn               |
 -------------------------
| { a: 'data', b: 'data' } |
```

If an update is submitted with *only* the following `{ c: 'data' }`, the same record would end up like so :

```
| jsoncolumn                         |
 ------------------------------------
| { a: 'data', b: 'data', c: 'data } |
```

I've read around that merging json with postgres was not a big deal, but i'm not that sure about how to process such things correctly (a trigger on record update ?)

Thx for sharing your expertise on that one

BEST

Comment: So nothing could ever be deleted from that column via an update? What if it already has `{ c: 'data' }` and you update it to `{ c: 'data' }`, what then? Or if it has `{ c: 'data1' }` and your update is `{ c: 'data2' }`?

Comment: you're right. but by that, you mean there's no solution ?